# Running parallel integration tests in separate working directories

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, parallel-testing

I want to speed up my integration tests by running them in parallel. The  configuration in maven-failsafe-plugin enables that, dividing all my tests among a number of parallel test runners, but my application puts various kinds of data in the working directory and the tests stomp on each other. How can I run each test/thread of tests in a separate directory?

If I could somehow set the working directory according to a system property of the test runner then surefire/failsafe offer a `${surefire.forkNumber}` placeholder that would seem the solution, but that's not expanded in the straightforward `<workingDirectory>` property (instead all threads run tests in a directory literally named ${surefire.forkNumber}).

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in failsafe 2.19 by [SUREFIRE-1136](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1136).